# RCP: How to call a class from a command handler

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have a menu which has a label bound to a command.

Lets say:

plugin.xml

```
<menu label="Settings">
         <command 
            commandId="prototype.standalone.MainDirectory"
            label="Main">
         </command>
</menu>

public class MainDirectory extends AbstractHandler {
    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
         // How can I call from here all my business methods from my main View. 
         // Do I have to use DI? If yes, can you give me an easy example related to this snippet?     
         return null;
    }
}
```

As asked in the comment. How can I call my methods? Because if I never instantiate an `MainDirectory` so I also can not just pass Objects from my `createControls` - I think that I have to use Dependency Injection but I don't know how. Can someone give me an example or an other solution

**Edit:** Or is it maybe possible to add a Listener to the menu Item? Would make all much easier. Didn't found anything

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be the easiest way **not** to create the menu with `org.eclipse.ui.menu` instead just use the basic `SWT Menu` and add it to the frame - I anyway have a standalone application, so the eclipse menu would be an overkill

Answer (score 0):

You should also have below in your `plugin.xml`

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
  <command
        defaultHandler="your MainDirectory class path"
        id="prototype.standalone.MainDirectory"
        name="My Label">
  </command>
</extension>
```